# Skip() and Take() in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to load data as follows-

```
var outletList = (from c in db.OutletList
                  where c.EmployeeId == 1 
                  orderby c.VisitId descending select c).Take(10).Skip(skipQuantity);

int quantity = outletList.Count();    // it's zero
```

No data is being loaded. I'm new to Entity Framework, so, sorry if it is a foolish question.

Any help?

Comment: You are taking 10 elements, and then skipping `skipQuantity` from those 10. If `skipQuantity` is greater or equal to 10, the result will be empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should first `Skip` from the whole collection and after that `Take`.

```
var outletList = (from c in db.OutletList
                    where c.EmployeeId == 1 
                    orderby c.VisitId descending select c)
                    .Skip(skipQuantity).Take(10);
```